# WebBrowser inside Asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser

I have an asp.net mvc website and inside a page, I would like to have a WebBrowser to browse other sites.

Is it possible ? OR at least to display a single external Webpage without leaving my page...

If yes, what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is an Web Project. not a native Application.

If you want to insert a WebBrowser, use Iframe tag in view page.

```
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com/path/to/show" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thx. This is what I was looking for. Some website cannot be displayed in a frame though...